# How can I fix react js npx module installation functioning error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

when I'm trying to use npx create-react-app MernCrud it not working properly I try to change the prefix path of npm config but its giving the same error and path doesn't change

I tried to install npm  then this came

> C:\Users\Pumudu Fernando\Desktop\ReactProject>npm install npm WARN
>   saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Pumudu
>   Fernando\Desktop\ReactProject\package.json' npm notice created a
>   lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
>
> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Users\Pumudu Fernando\Desktop\ReactProject\package.json' npm WARN
>   ReactProject No description npm WARN ReactProject No repository field.
>   npm WARN ReactProject No README data npm WARN ReactProject No license
>   field.

when try to npx create-react-app MernCrud

> C:\Users\Pumudu Fernando\Desktop\ReactProject>nox create-react-app
>   CrudMern 'nox' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> C:\Users\Pumudu Fernando\Desktop\ReactProject>npx create-react-app
>   CrudMern Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir
>   'C:\Users\Pumudu' TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
>       at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
>       at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:78:20
>       at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:228:22)
>       at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:266:24
>       at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:83:7
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:82:13
>       at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
>       at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:173:20)
>       at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:47:53
>   C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205   if
>   (npm.config.get('json')) {
>                    ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
>       at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:205:18)
>       at process.emit (events.js:189:13)
>       at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:496:27) Install for create-react-app@latest failed with code 7

It should create the project but that won't happen `npm start` also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the answer so i clear the cache  npm cache clean --force
 then i change the prefix path of config edit to
 C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm

then  i gave the command to administrator cmd 
 npm config set cache C:\tmp\nodejs\npm-cache --global after that
 npx create-react-app name work properly